# How did Konohamaru fool everyone in the Hidden Leaf Village?

Tags: naruto, boruto

There's a scene when Naruto was about to go to his inauguration as a Hokage but was knocked out by Himawari. In his stead, Konohamaru transformed into Naruto but nobody notices this from among those present.

How did Konohamaru fool everyone in the Hidden Leaf Village?

Comment: Um, he used Transformation Technique? Of course everyone would be fooled since it's used to change your appearance into someone else's. Unless someone saw you transforming, then obviously, they would not know :)

Comment: because joinin can sense chakra and and some can tell different sents basically sensory type can easily notice them.

Comment: Yes, but since that was an inauguration, I don't think anyone even thought of trying to find out if the hokage was Naruto or Konohamaru. Most likely because nothing suspicious happened. That Naruto was declared hokage, that was probably what's important for them at that moment :)

Comment: And who would expect the guy that's been screaming since childhood he was going to be hokage to miss his own inauguration :-P

Comment: @Gravinco expected his daughter to rage and one hit him haha

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @W.Are in the comments, nobody witnessed Konohamaru perform the [Transformation Justu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Transformation_Technique). With enough skill, the transformation turns the user into a perfect replica.

> The transformation of a skilled shinobi will be exactly like the genuine article, **so it will be impossible to tell the two apart**
>   <sub>(emphasis my own)</sub>

While shinobi who have the ability to detect [chakra](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra) signatures (such as sensory types) could have easily detected this had they been actively looking for it, this was an inauguration ceremony during a time of peace. The thought of an imposter was probably not on their minds.